# Drop Down List first row empty using tsql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a legacy application that using table driven design. I have built a custom drop down list with the years between 1950 and the current year + 1.

My issue is that when I finished it, i got my empty label `''` and then the years starting with 1950, and I need to start with the empty label `''` and then the current year plus one and desc.

The following shows where I am at. I added an `Order by` which worked great except now my empty label `''` is the very last item in the list. I still want it to be first.

```
DECLARE @begin int = 1950
DECLARE @end int = YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1;

with foo (Year) as
(
select @begin as num
UNION ALL 
SELECT Year+1 from foo
where Year <@end


)
SELECT '' AS Value, '' AS Label UNION
select  CAST(Year AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Value, CAST(Year AS VARCHAR(4)) Label from foo 
where Year between @begin and @end

Order by Value desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add one more column for ordering like this:

```
DECLARE @begin int = 1950
DECLARE @end int = YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1;

with foo (Year) as
(
    select @begin as num
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Year+1 from foo
    where Year <@end
), 
DataSource AS
(
SELECT 0 AS [RowID]
      ,'' AS Value
      ,'' AS Label 
UNION
SELECT 1 AS [RowID]
      ,CAST(YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Value
      ,CAST(YEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Label 
FROM foo 
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN @begin AND @end
)
SELECT Value
      ,Label
FROM DataSource
ORDER BY RowID ASC
        ,Value DESC
```